# Normalizing an adjacency list

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I have data represented in this fashion (not sure I properly call it an *adjacency* list, but that's the best description I can think of):

```
+--------+-------+
| Level  | ID    |
+========+=======+
| Parent | A-123 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | B-123 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | B-456 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | B-789 |
+--------+-------+
| Parent | A-456 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | C-123 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | C-456 |
+--------+-------+
| Child  | C-789 |
+--------+-------+
```

I need to transform it to this format:

```
+--------+-------+
| Parent | Child |
+========+=======+
| A-123  | B-123 |
+--------+-------+
| A-123  | B-456 |
+--------+-------+
| A-123  | B-789 |
+--------+-------+
| A-456  | C-123 |
+--------+-------+
| A-456  | C-456 |
+--------+-------+
| A-456  | C-789 |
+--------+-------+
```

I think this can be done with an SQL window function (I would use `sqlite` for simplicity) and I'm sure `pandas` has some tricks in its bag as well, but in any case, I'm not very familiar with these more advanced techniques.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the relationship between the rows?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so how do you know which parent corresponds to which child?

Comment: Just the order of the row. Any child row is the child of its preceding parent.

Comment: . . There is no such thing.  SQL tables are *unordered*.

Comment: At this point, my source is an Excel spreadsheet. I could upload it into an sqlite table with an row ID as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas solution - replace rows after `Parent` to missing values and forward filling `ID`, then remove rows with `Parent` and rename columns:

```
m = df['Level'].eq('Parent')

df['Level'] = df['ID'].where(m).ffill()
df = df[~m].rename(columns={'Level':'Parent','ID':'Child'})
print (df)
  Parent Child
1   A123  B123
2   A123  B456
3   A123  B789
5   A456  C123
6   A456  C456
7   A456  C789
```

Comment: nice one! So if I understand the process, we're extracting a series of boolean-values mapping the `level` column (true if parent), then we replace the values of levels with the parent ID's by forward-filling the last parent to its subsequent children,  and finally we keep only entries where the orginal row is not a parent. Any day I learned something is a good day, so thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that represents the ordering, then you can use SQL:

```
select tp.id as parent, t.id as child
from (select t.*,
             max(case when level = 'Parent' then <order col> end) over (order by <order col>) as parent_ord_col
      from t
     ) t join
     t tp
     on tp.<order col> = t.parent_ord_col and tp.level = 'Parent'
where t.level = 'Child';
```

Comment: Is that T-SQL? I might be able to find a server to run it in.

Comment: Good opportinity for me to learn some T-SQL tricks! Thank you! :-)